# Scala Swing: How to pan an image using your mouse?

Tags: swing, scala

I have been trying to replicate some [Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341857/how-to-pan-an-image-using-your-mouse-in-java-swing) work in Scala. In the code below `this` extends Scala Swings `ScrollPane`.

```
myPanel.reactions +={
    case MouseDragged(_,x,_) => {
      //val viewport = this.viewportView.get.asInstanceOf[JViewport]
      val viewport = this.contents.head.self.asInstanceOf[JComponent].getParent.asInstanceOf[JViewport]
      println(viewport.getViewPosition)
      val vp = viewport.getViewPosition
      var cp = x.getLocation
      vp.translate(point.x-cp.x,point.y-cp.y)
      //newLoc = new Point(vp.getX)
      val jComp = contents.head.asInstanceOf[JComponent]
      jComp.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(vp,viewport.getSize: Dimension))
    }
    case MousePressed(_,x,_,_,_) => point = x.getLocation
    case MouseClicked(_,_,_,_,_) => println("click")
}
```

I can't see how to get access to the `Viewport` object as in the Java code in the related question. How should this be implemented in Scala Swing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  myPanel.reactions +={
    case MouseDragged(myPanel,x,_) => {
      val cp = x.getLocation
      this.horizontalScrollBar.value += point.x-cp.x
      this.verticalScrollBar.value += point.y-cp.y
      point = cp
    }
    case MousePressed(_,x,_,_,_) => point = x.getLocation
  }
```